# XML Phone validation

Tags: xml

How to write an xml to convert a phone number from (123) 4567890 to 1234567890?
Either using a Regex or convert statements?

Thanks

Comment: Questions are encouraged to provide a [Minimum Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), try to [improve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) yours. XML: _Extensible Markup Language (XML) is a markup language that defines a set of rules for **encoding** documents in a format that is both human-readable and machine-readable._ Data manipulation is done on the language used to build the XML.

Comment: You could write code to convert a phone number in any number of languages, but not in XML. XML is data, and data doesn't convert things.